# Kotlin: Show non-null values with separator

Tags: kotlin

I want to show non-null values for my description, but for some reason native function is bugging out and I dont understand why.

Code:

```
val formattedDesc = listOfNotNull(boardingZone, accessPoint, duration, description).joinToString { " • " }
```

This should show string like this: `"120 • A3 • 30 minutes • Ticket"`

If some of those strings are null it should not be there.

But this function is returning this value: `"•, •"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `.joinToString { " • " }` you are passing `{ " * "}` as the final, functional parameter and all the other parameters the their defaults. So looking at the signature of `joinToString` it is:

`public fun <T> Iterable<T>.joinToString(separator: CharSequence = ", ", prefix: CharSequence = "", postfix: CharSequence = "", limit: Int = -1, truncated: CharSequence = "...", transform: ((T) -> CharSequence)? = null)`

so separator, prefix, postfix, limit and truncated are all the defaults and `transform` is `{ " • " }` which runs on each element of your non-null list. So any non-null values are replaced with " • " whuch us the output you are seeing.

I guess you actually want:

`listOfNotNull(boardingZone, accessPoint, duration, description).joinToString(" • ")`

or even better use:

`listOfNotNull(boardingZone, accessPoint, duration, description).joinToString(separator = " • ")`

so that both you and readers of your code are sure what parameter is being passed.

Comment: And to avoid this class of problems entirely, you may also use a named parameter: `.joinToString(separator = " • ")`

Comment: Good point @Joffrey,  I'll add that so it's clear.